# python - What is the fastest way to replace lines of a file from a dictionary?

Tags: python, performance, dictionary, io, mapping

I have 1K files each having 1M lines.
I have a dictionary that has around 2M keys and assigns them to 2M unique numbers from 1 to 2M. So The entries are like the following:

```
dictionary = {
    'hakuchita.mutikama' : 3,
    'mitiputu.mitanata' : 4,
    'pulasika.rukayota' : 1,
    'luschi.rulu.pitana' : 2
}
```

Each line of each file is one of these keys. And I want to replace all of these keys with their values.

Here is my code:

```
for filename in os.listdir('data'):
    with fileinput.FileInput('data/' + filename, inplace=True) as file:
        for line in file:
            print(dictionary[line[:-1]])
```

But I just ran my code and it's taking ages.

What is the fastest way to get this done?

Comment: Instead of stripping the newline character from each line of input, add a newline to your dictionary keys. That will save a billion slice operations.

Comment: @chepner Good point. Thanks! actually 2B because I removed them from the dictionary too! lol.

Comment: Define "ages" .

Comment: @StefanPochmann from Piacenzian to Zanclean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of getting each key one by one and calling the dictionary separately, you can do it at once. Say one of your text files contains this:

```
hakuchita.mutikama
mitiputu.mitanata
luschi.rulu.pitana
```

Get all keys at once:

```
with open("sampleText.txt","r") as f:
    keys = f.read().splitlines()
```

This is your dictionary in the OP:

```
dictionary = {
    'hakuchita.mutikama' : 3,
    'mitiputu.mitanata' : 4,
    'pulasika.rukayota' : 1,
    'luschi.rulu.pitana' : 2
}
```

Get all values now:

```
values = [dictionary[e] for e in keys]
```

Result:

```
[3, 4, 2]
```

Now, as @chepner brilliantly points out in his comment, if you do:

```
dictionary = dict([(k+'\n',v) for k,v in dictionary.items()])
```

you can get rid of the `.splitlines()` in my above code, read the file using `keys = f.readlines()`, and save the time `.splitlines()` would take. You can optimize this whole procedure by parallel-processing, as @JuanAntonio mentions.

Comment: You can't use a list comprehension as-is if you get rid of `splitlines`, since `e` will be a single character rather than a complete key at each iteration.

Comment: @chepner Absolutely, thanks for pointing that out. Reading should change to `f.readlines()` in that case, I'll include this in my edit right now.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [multiprocessing](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html) python package that simplify threading (among others) to speed up your code.

[Here](http://www.blopig.com/blog/2016/08/processing-large-files-using-python/) you can see a good post where is talking about and some [videos](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Lu5LrKh1Zno&list=RDLu5LrKh1Zno).

Answer (score 1):

The slowdown is happening because you're doing a line-by-line write. Instead write all of the data into a string (1 million lines should still be okay to store in memory) and write the file out in one go.